# How to save the attributedText UITextView to the database

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, uitextview, nsattributedstring

The attributedText data structure is as follows

```
S{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd82c717bc0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSOriginalFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd82c717bc0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 2.90954, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 1, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}hepi{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd82c717bc0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 2.90954, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 1, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

**I want to save it, when the user re-open the app can see these again in UITextView (not to lose the font parameters such as color, font size)**

I try to save it as a String to the database, but I can not use it for the attributedText of UITextView

**In addition it may contain pictures in UITextView**

**The database I use is Realm  Is there any way to achieve it?**

If you can, take the above data structure to do a demo that's the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`-[NSAttributedString dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1534090-datafromrange?language=objc) to convert your `NSAttributedString` into an `NSData` that you can store in Realm. You can then use [`-[NSAttributedString initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata?language=objc) to go in the reverse direction, from `NSData` back to `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: This is a good idea, I now try to achieve it.In addition, if there is a picture (NSTextAttachment), converted into Data can be saved?

Comment: If you elect to use a format that supports image attachments, such as RTFD, then yes, you should be able to round trip such attachments.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the problem with your suggestion